# Django m2m_changed signal, post_add is called automatically after post_remove

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-signals

I want to remove user from Tank's moderatos, when user is removed from Tank's users field.
but when i called `instance.moderators.remove(*pk_set)` it is removed and then added again by post_add signal.

works in this way `users.pre_remove > users.post_remove > moderators.pre_remove > moderators.post_remove > moderators.pre_add > moderators.post_add`

the last two (pre_add, post_add) are getting called unnecessarily

I am using Django admin page for these operations.

Model :

```
class Tank(models.Model):
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                              related_name="tank", default=1)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               related_name="tanks", blank=True)
        hidden_for_users = models.ManyToManyField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="hidden_tanks",
        blank=True)
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name="tanks_of_admin", blank=True)
    moderators = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    related_name="tanks_of_moderator", blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Signals :

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Tank)
def set_attr_if_needed(instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # set ttype
    if not instance.ttype:
        obj, _ = Type.objects.get_or_create(name='overhead tank')
        instance.ttype = obj

@receiver(post_save, sender=Tank)
def create_device_offline_notification(instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Notification.query.fetch_or_create(instance, "device offline")
    
def __add_users_to_location(instance):
    """ add tank's users to location's users """
    location = instance.locations.filter(
        location_type__name='Apartment').first()
    if location:
        location.users.add(*instance.users.all())


def __copy_addition_to_users(instance, users):
    """ add moderators and admins to users list """
    instance.users.add(*users)

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Tank.users.through)
def on_tank_users_change(instance, action,pk_set, **_):
    if action == 'post_add':
        __add_users_to_location(instance=instance)
    elif action == 'post_remove':
        instance.moderators.remove(*pk_set)



@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Tank.moderators.through)
def on_tank_moderators_change(instance, action,pk_set, **_):
    if action == 'post_add':
        __copy_addition_to_users(users=pk_set, instance=instance)
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your signals?

Comment: @GwynBleidD yes, i have updated the question. please take a look.